# WordPress - Accidentally renamed wp_content

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I was modifying some files using a plugin in wp-admin and I accidentally renamed the wp-content folder.

I still have administrator access to wp-admin and direct PHPAdmin access to the database, but I don't have FTP.

Obviously all of my plugins are unfindable (in the disconnected content folder) so I can't go back in the way I went.

Is there anyway I can get back in there to rename the folder, or have wordpress rebuild the folder? Possibly in MySQL.

Ideally without contacting the site admin.

EDIT
I tried uploading a php script to the media section but I need direct code access to allow the filetype override.

Comment: I may sound stupid, Contact your host and ask them to rename the folder for you.

Comment: What plugin lets you rename core folders and how is that allowed on the repository...?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone There's a plugin for everything [https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-manager/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-manager/)

Comment: Can you try and install new plugins from the admin and does this recreate the directory for you?

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone unfortunately no. If it can't find the folder it asks for FTP access.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to force an update of WordPress and see if that recreates the folder for you, apart from that I think you will need FTP